# DSWI brief description

Tags: water, agriculture

What is the brief description of Disease Stress Water Index ([DSWI](https://www.indexdatabase.de/db/i-single.php?id=106))? According to the link, it has been defined as to detect water-stressed crops at a canopy level. I am looking for a bit more information on this index.

Comment: This might be on-topic in [earthscience.se], but it isn't GIS-centric enough for GIS SE.

Comment: So, it does not fall under the vegetation-index tag? And since cross posting is not allowed, should I delete this question before posting it on Earth Science to avoid duplication?

Comment: @Arthur_Morgan I'll migrate it for you but if you ever don't want to wait for a moderator to do that just deleting here and re-asking there is fine too.